# How do i simplify an array of directions {"south", "east"} etc etc, in order?

Tags: java, arrays, list, algorithm, sorting

```
    public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {

        List<String> objects = Arrays.asList(arr);

        long northCount = (objects.contains("NORTH")) ? objects.stream().filter("NORTH"::contains).count() : 0;
        long southCount = (objects.contains("SOUTH")) ? objects.stream().filter("SOUTH"::contains).count() : 0;
        long eastCount = (objects.contains("EAST")) ? objects.stream().filter("EAST"::contains).count() : 0;
        long westCount = (objects.contains("WEST")) ? objects.stream().filter("WEST"::contains).count() : 0;

        Map<String, Long> doubleBraceMap  = new HashMap<String, Long>() {{
            put("NORTH", (long)((northCount >= southCount) ? (northCount - southCount) : 0));
            put("SOUTH", (long)((southCount >= northCount) ? (southCount - northCount) : 0));
            put("EAST", (long)((eastCount >= westCount) ? (eastCount - westCount) : 0));
            put("WEST", (long)((westCount >= eastCount) ? (westCount - eastCount) : 0));
        }};

        List<String> formattedArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        doubleBraceMap.keySet().forEach(key ->{

            for(int i = 0; i < doubleBraceMap.get(key); i++) {
                formattedArray.add(key);
            }

        });

        return formattedArray.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

the code above simplifies the locations BUT not in order, in order being that the positions of the elements don't change only redundant movements do, for example {"SOUTH", "NORTH", "EAST"} becomes "EAST" as south and north cancel out, my algorithm above doesnt look at positions, it just simplifies it by calculating the number of souths, norths etc, then doing some basic maths. PS, i'd like this problem to be solved **without** nested loops, if possible.

**Problem**, 
Write a function dirReduc which will take an array of strings and returns an array of strings with the needless directions removed (W<->E or S<->N side by side).

Comment: `objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: Does "South East North" simplify to "East" also?

Comment: Thanks for replying @JohannesKuhn, but could you explain what the line of code does?

Comment: @Joni Yes South east north would simplify to east, is essentially simplifies it in order

Comment: You haven't asked a question other than "How do I solve this problem," Your requirements are ambiguous. You need to show us some examples: sample input, sample output, and explain the rules that transform input to output. And if your program isn't giving you the expected output, show us the output it is giving.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, use a plain old for-each loop:

```
public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {
    int northsouth = 0, eastwest = 0;
    for (String dir : arr) {
        switch (dir) {
            case "NORTH" -> northsouth++;
            case "EAST" -> eastwest++;
            case "SOUTH" -> northsouth--;
            case "WEST" -> eastwest--;
        }
    }
    int size = Math.abs(northsouth) + Math.abs(eastwest);
    String[] result = new String[size];
    if (northsouth > 0) {
        Arrays.fill(result, 0, northsouth, "NORTH");
    } else {
        Arrays.fill(result, 0, -northsouth, "SOUTH");
    }
    if (eastwest > 0) {
        Arrays.fill(result, size-eastwest, size, "EAST");
    } else {
        Arrays.fill(result,  size+eastwest, size, "WEST");
    }
    return result;
}
```

No need to get fancy here.

Comment: sadly that didnt give me the needed results.

Comment: Why not? It does the same thing as your code does. Are you sure that you can simplify `NORTH EAST SOUTH` to `EAST`? Also, what java version are you using? (This uses arrow labels, which are new in Java 14)

Comment: Well, for this particular problem, I’m using java 8.